# Store SortExpression and SortDirection from GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How I can save the SortExpression and SortDirection that are in the property OnSorting from GridView, I know I have to use session but how can I do that? Because I want to retrieve it in `Page_load` like this:

```
myGridView.sort(sortExpression, sortDirection);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set and retrieve from Session like this:

```
    // Set
    Session["SortExpression"] = "Fname";
    Session["SortDirection"] = (int)SortDirection.Ascending;

   // Retrieve
   SortDirection sortDir =     
        (SortDirection)Enum.ToObject(typeof(SortDirection),  
         (int)Session["SortDirection"]);
   string sortExpression = Session["SortField"].ToString();
```

Comment: Nice, but the problem is I have 6 column in gridview how I can save it from onSorting, my aim is I have gridviw to do a search ok the user do srarch and appear records related to that search then within gridview I have hyperlink to go next page when user click it then go back to that page of having gridview the whole records are lost, I want when user go back to have the aame search when he was left

Comment: until now I can retrive the filter and paging but sorting I can got it so I want to save the last sortExpression and SortDirection in session and retrive it in page_load, do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: You can get the last sort by adding grid event Sort then looking a e.SortExpression and e.SortDirection properties of GridViewSortEventArgs.

Comment: I do like this: protected void gv_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
        {
            Session["sortExpression"] = e.SortExpression;
            Session["sortDirection"] = e.SortDirection;
        }

Comment: in page_load: if (Session["sortExpression"] != null)
                {
                    gvt.Sort(Session["sortExpression"].ToString(), Session["sortDirection"] );
                    Session.Remove("sortExpression");
                }

Comment: but I get error for the Session["sortDirection"] it not recognize

Comment: yes I fix it, I do like you wrote about sortDirection: if (Session["sortExpression"] != null && Session["sortDirection"] != null)
                {
                    SortDirection sortDir =
                    (SortDirection)Enum.ToObject(typeof(SortDirection),
                    (int)Session["sortDirection"]);

                    gv.Sort(Session["sortExpression"].ToString(), sortDir);
                    Session.Remove("sortExpression");
                    Session.Remove("sortDirection");
                }